# Starlette's Middleware causes HTTP communication to stall

Tags: python, middleware, fastapi, starlette

I try to make custom middleware to validate upload file in http requests.
sample code:

```py
    class MyMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
        ...
        async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next: RequestResponseEndpoint) ->  Response:
            scope = request.scope

            if scope["method"] not in ("POST", "PUT"):
                response = await call_next(request)
                return response

            form = await request.form()
            content_type = form[next(iter(form))].content_type
            if content_type not in self.file_type:
                return _unsupported_media_type

        response = await call_next(request)
        return response
```

But, `response = await call_next(request)` causes HTTP communication to stall when using above middleware in FastAPI.
like below pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FO5E.png)

Thank you for reading!

---

This code based on these:

- [starlette_early_data](https://github.com/HarrySky/starlette-early-data/blob/master/starlette_early_data.py)
- [starlette_csrf](https://github.com/frankie567/starlette-csrf/blob/main/starlette_csrf/middleware.py)

Comment: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/495) I’d suggest you to use a dependency instead of the middleware.

Comment: @alex_noname Thanks for your comment. I'd implement to use a dependency!